# Ubuntu jammy no longer has a release file

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, lts

So I tried to do `sudo apt update` but then there's error like this:

```
E: The repository 'http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

My knowledge about ubuntu is not much, but I believe those are the main ubuntu repository for packages right?

Btw here's the result if I type `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

I believe this is the most recent lts version of ubuntu right? Is it possible that this longer supported?

Comment: No, it's not the main server, it's a regional one that probably has a (temporary) problem. Try changing to the main one (Software & Updates).

Comment: A list of available servers is available at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors  ps:  I'm getting errors on ossmirror.mycloud.services myself thus I concur with @ChanganAuto's suggestion

Comment: Don't know that there's such thing as regional server, thanks for noticing! @ChanganAuto

Comment: Thanks for the list! @guiverc